# video not loading when sent in chunks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-streams

the component with video element

```
const Post = ({ title, description, postimg, postvideo }) => {
  const url = import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_URL;
  const [imgdata, setImagedata] = useState(null);
  const [videodata, setVideodata] = useState(`${url}/uploads/video?src=${postvideo}`);
  const fetchVideo= async (event)=>{
    console.log('fetch     ......')
    const currentTime = event?.target?.currentTime;
    const duration = event?.target?.duration;
    const start=Math.floor(currentTime / duration) || 0;
    const video=postvideo ? await getVideo(postvideo,{start}) : null
    const url=URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([video],{ type: 'video/mp4' }))
    setVideodata(url)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImage = async () => {
      const img = postimg ? await getImage(postimg) : null;
      setImagedata(img);
    };
    
    if(postimg) fetchImage();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="title">
        <h3>{title}</h3>
      </div>
      {postimg ? (
        <div className="img">
          <img src={URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([imgdata]))} alt="img" />
        </div>
      ) : null}
      {postvideo ? (
        <div className="img">
          <video  alt="img" controls onTimeUpdate={(event)=>{fetchVideo(event)}}>
            <source src={videodata}></source>
          </video>
        </div>
      ) : null}
      <div className="description">{description}</div>
      <div className="buttons">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComment} />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShare} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

function sending request:

```
export const getVideo=async (src,{start})=>{
    const token=localStorage.getItem('token');
    if(token){
    try {
        const headers={
            token,
            start
        }
        const response=await fetch(`${url}/uploads/video?src=${src}`,{
            headers,
        });
        const reader=response.body.getReader();
        const data=(await reader.read()).value;
        console.log(data)
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
}
```

backend code (node+express):

```
export const getVideo=(req,res)=>{
    const {src}=req.query;

    console.log('hiiiiiiii jfhwefher')
    try{
        let {start}=req.headers;
        const filesize=fs.statSync(`${__dirname}/${src}`).size;
        start=(parseInt(start)*filesize) || 0
        const chunksize=10**10
        const end=Math.min(start+chunksize,filesize)
        console.log(`${start}-${end}`)
        const rs=fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/${src}`,{start,end});
        rs.on('end',()=>{
            return res.end();
        })
        rs.pipe(res);
        rs.on('error',(error)=>{
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).send({success:false,error})
        })
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I am sending req from react to node with auth token and source of video in header. the node  server is sending video in chunks but which is converted into blob and then in objecturl in frontend.
But the video dont loads when sent in chunk , but when sent as whole it works fine.